# Old TV show (80’s/90’s) about this boy who finds something in his dad's room that allows him to summon a winged creature/monster

Tags: story-identification, tv, animation

I was on Netflix a while ago, and saw an old TV show ('80s/'90s) about this boy who finds something in his dad's room and then the bad guys come after him. It’s some kid of creature/monster that he summons, which has wings attached to his body, so he can glide and fly. He gets chased then goes into a river. He then comes out and meets two people who show him how to summon and use these monsters to fight and find legendary and strong monsters, to make sure the enemies don't get their hands on them.

Comment: Live action? Or cartoon? And does he have the wings, or is it the creature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just based off of the main character finding a device in his father's room that lets him summon creatures, meeting others who can do the same, and being pursued by an evil organization, I'm going to guess [*Huntik: Secrets & Seekers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huntik:_Secrets_%26_Seekers)

[image: Splash image for Huntik: Secrets & Seekers]

> Season one focuses on the fight against the evil Organization, led by a powerful Seeker known as the Professor. Along the way, the team discovers the Amulet of Will and the powerful Legendary Titans. Though the Professor eventually acquires the three Legendary Titans of Mind, Body, and Spirit in a bid for immortality, he is defeated by the Huntik team.

....

> Lok is the son of the legendary Seeker, Eathon Lambert. Though bored by his textbooks, he is excellent at solving puzzles. Lok grew up knowing nothing about being a Seeker until he discovered his father's Amulet. He aspires to be a top Seeker like his father. During season 1, Lok is a key member of the team that took down the Professor, Simon Judeau. During season 2, Lok becomes the new Champion of Casterwill to fight against the Blood Spiral. As the story progresses, he develops romantic feelings for Sophie. Lok's Titan is Kipperin, a green flying moth.

### Show Opening